# How to create an Element-create method inside a class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I want to create a class 'Element' in JavaScript that contains a method 'create'. This Method is ought to create any Elements (without appending them yet). Therefor I need to loop throug an object literal of unknown length. So far the rest operator didn't solve my problems.

```
I tried different configurations of my code, but I don't get ir right.

class Element
{
    static create( {type, attr : { ...(k : v) }, content } )
    {
    let el = document.createElement(type);
    for ( let i; i < attr.length; i++ )
    {
        el.setAttribute(k, v);
    }
    el.innerHTML = content;
    return el;
    }
}

// Element.create({type: 'p', attr: {'class' : 'foo', 'style' : 'color:green'}, content : 'I am a p-Element.'});
// desired output: <p class="foo" style="color:green">I am a p-Element</p>
```

Comment: In your for loop you are calling attr.length, yet attr is an object by the looks of it. Try making attr into an array and your for loop would work, what is your error?

Comment: attr is not iterable. I tried ..., attr:[...k:v]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this corrent way to do what you want

```
class Element
{
    static create( {type, attr, content } )
    {
    let el = document.createElement(type);
    for(let key in attr){
        el.setAttribute(key, attr[key]);
    }
    el.innerHTML = content;
    return el;
    }
}
```

Now you will get your expected output